# Most efficient way of creating dynamic HTML content in web view

Tags: jquery

We are still trying to figure out which gives best performance for web apps that work inside a web view. Our app is mainly designed for Ipads where the UI content runs inside a web view. Performance is the primary importance for us but we are left with confusions on choosing which is the best way to do .Here we use two methods on drawing dynamic HTML and we can't decide which is the best way to do.

The operation follows by taking a JSON data and draw a table by looping the JSON.

***Method 1.***

```
scope.list = result.deviceData;
var div=$('<div>').addClass('full-_width').css({'width':'830px','align':'center','font-family':'serif','font-weight':'bold','font-size':'20px'});
        var table=$('<table>').attr({'cellpadding':'1','cellspacing':'1','class':'display','id':'example','align':'center'}).appendTo(div);
        $('<thead>').css({'background-color':'#C69C74','align':'center'}).appendTo(table);
        var tr=$('<tr>').addClass('ColorHead').attr({'align':'center'}).appendTo(table);
        $('<th>').attr({'align':'center'}).addClass('CatTitleText').css({'style':'width:125px'}).append('<br/>').html('Room&nbsp;Number&nbsp').appendTo(tr);
        $('<th>').attr({'align':'center'}).addClass('CatTitleText').css({'style':'width:125px'}).append('<br/>').html('IP&nbsp;Address&nbsp').appendTo(tr);
        $('<th>').attr({'align':'center'}).addClass('CatTitleText').css({'style':'width:125px'}).append('<br/>').html('App&nbsp;Version&nbsp').appendTo(tr);
        $('<th>').attr({'align':'center'}).addClass('CatTitleText').css({'style':'width:125px'}).append('<br/>').html('OS&nbsp;Version&nbsp').appendTo(tr);
        $('<th>').attr({'align':'center'}).addClass('CatTitleText').css({'style':'width:125px'}).append('<br/>').html('SIP&nbsp;Status&nbsp').appendTo(tr);

$.each(scope.list, function(index, eachObj) {
var tr1=$('<tr>').css({'height':'40px','cursor':'pointer'}).attr({'deviceId':eachObj.deviceId,'ipAddress':eachObj.ipAddress});
            var td1=$('<td>').addClass('CatNormalText').css({'border':'1px','align':'left'});
            if(eachObj.deviceId==null || eachObj.deviceId=="")
                {td1.html('N/A');
                }else{
                    td1.html(eachObj.deviceId);
                }
            td1.appendTo(tr1);
            var td2=$('<td>').addClass('CatNormalText').css({'border':'1px','align':'left'});
            if(eachObj.ipAddress==null || eachObj.ipAddress=="")
                {td2.html('N/A');}
            else{td2.html(eachObj.ipAddress);}
            td2.appendTo(tr1);
            var td3=$('<td>').addClass('CatNormalText').css({'border':'1px','align':'left'});
            if(eachObj.appVersion==null || eachObj.appVersion==""){td3.html('N/A');}
            else{td3.html(eachObj.appVersion);}
            td3.appendTo(tr1);
            var td4=$('<td>').addClass('CatNormalText').css({'border':'1px','align':'left'});
            if(eachObj.deviceOSVersion==null || eachObj.deviceOSVersion==""){td4.html('N/A');}
            else{td4.html(eachObj.deviceOSVersion);}
            td4.appendTo(tr1);
            var td5=$('<td>').addClass('CatNormalText').css({'border':'1px','align':'left'});
            if(eachObj.sipStatus=="Registered"){
                td5.append($('<img>').attr({'src':'circle-green.png','height':'13px','width':'13px'})).html('&nbsp;&nbsp'+eachObj.sipStatus);
            }
            else{
                td5.append($('<img>').attr({'src':'circle_red.png','height':'13px','width':'13px'})).html('&nbsp;&nbsp'+eachObj.sipStatus);
            }
            td5.appendTo(tr1);
            tr1.appendTo(table);
            table.appendTo(div);
            $('#dashboard').append(div);
});
```

***Method 2:***

```
var html ="";
        html = html+"<div class='full_width' style='width: 830px;' align='center' style='font-family:serif;font-weight:bold;font-size: 20px;'>";
        html = html+"<table cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1' class='display' id='example' align='center' style=''>";
        html = html+"<thead style='background-color:#C69C74;' align='center' >";
        html = html+"<tr class='ColorHead' align='center'>";
        html = html+"<th align='center' class='CatTitleText'style='width:125px'><br/>Room&nbsp;Number&nbsp;</th>";
        html = html+"<th align='center' class='CatTitleText' style='width:125px'><br/>IP&nbsp;Address&nbsp;</th>";
        html = html+"<th align='center' class='CatTitleText' style='width:115px'><br/>App&nbsp;Version&nbsp;</th>";
        html = html+"<th align='center' class='CatTitleText' style='width:105px'><br/>OS&nbsp;Version&nbsp;</th>";
        html = html+"<th align='center' class='CatTitleText' style='width:128px'><br/>SIP&nbsp;Status&nbsp;</th>";
        html = html+"</tr></thead><tbody>";
$.each(scope.list, function(index, eachObj) {
html += "<tr class='' style='height:40px;cursor:pointer' deviceId='"+eachObj.deviceId+ "'ipAddress='"+eachObj.ipAddress+"'>" +
                    "<td class='CatNormalText' style='border: 1px;' align='left'  >"+
                    ((eachObj.deviceId==null || eachObj.deviceId=="")?"N/A":eachObj.deviceId)+"</td>" +
                    "<td class='CatNormalText' style='border: 1px;' align='left'>"+
                    ((eachObj.ipAddress==null || eachObj.ipAddress=="")?"N/A":eachObj.ipAddress)+"</td>" +
                    "<td class='CatNormalText' style='border: 1px;' align='left'>"+
                    ((eachObj.appVersion==null || eachObj.appVersion=="")?"N/A":eachObj.appVersion)+"</td>" +
                    "<td class='CatNormalText' style='border: 1px;' align='left'>"+
                    ((eachObj.deviceOSVersion==null || eachObj.deviceOSVersion=="")?"N/A":eachObj.deviceOSVersion)+"</td>" +
                    "<td class='CatNormalText' style='border: 1px;' align='left'>"+
                    ((eachObj.sipStatus=="Registered")?"<img src='circle-green.png' height='13px' width='13px'>&nbsp;&nbsp;"+eachObj.sipStatus:
                            "<img src='circle_red.png' height='13px' width='13px'>&nbsp;&nbsp;"+eachObj.sipStatus)
                            +"</td></tr>";
        });
        html = html+"</tbody></table></div>";
        $('#dashboard').html(html);
});
```

Sorry for the poor arrangement of the code ,but as u can see from the above example which is the best way to draw dynamic HTML, using jquery to draw as object or draw HTML as string and append to jquery using the .HTML() method.

Comment: And what performance your tests shows to you? Also remove inline style as it can be moved to CSS leading to faster JS execution

Comment: both methods contains inline style sheets ,I used firefox to test the performance by setting start and end time , the difference was 2 when string was appended as .html()  and 8 when drawn with jquery objects